# Oracle 10g Database - SYSTEM tablespace space

Tags: oracle, tablespaces, oracle-10g-r2

I am concerned about the SYSTEM tablespace. It's space is 99% full. The whole tablespace has 1510 MB and there is 1507 MB already used. Max size of datafile is 32 GB and the autoincrement is on with increment 10 MB. However, I had outside company's audit and they pointed us it is unacceptable to keep so less free space in the system tablespace (3MB). As far as I see it is autoextensible, I am not sure if I should take any actions to resize the datafile (for example to 2 GB). I am not sure what kind of extents (DBA_EXTENTS) shall be storaged in this space, so at this moment I am not able to check if anything shall be moved from this space to SYSAUX or others. My question is, if it is really required to resize the system tablespace to avoid some problems with database due to its fullness? What would you do with this case? Maybe it would be enough to change incrementation size from 10 MB to more?

Comment: Did this audit not care that you're running Oracle 10g which has been out of support for over a decade? If SYSTEM can autoextend and there is available filesystem space then there is no problem. What was this audit supposed to be doing? I would recommend a second opinion.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer :) of course they did, there is much more they pointed out (it is like a dozen pages of report), but the thing is that there was no DBA before in the company that I just started to work, database where cared by outsourced company and they just did nothing with this. So I was hired not very long ago and I am expected to clean up a 'mess', like doubled or broken indexes etc.. and that is how my question appeared :) however, there is a plan for nearly future to migrate the DB to Oracle 19c and..to linux. yep :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.
The real question should be: what objects are created in your system tablespace. Normally there should be close to zero tables/partitions in the system tablespace.
Application objects should be in application tablespaces. Not in system.

If your application has a lot of stored procedures/packages/functions/views they will take space in system because the source of those objects is in there.

Check for application tables and move them to application tablespaces. Adjust the owner of those tables to have an application tablespace as their default tablespace.

This all ofcourse assumes that the owner of the application tablespaces is not one like sys or system.

Comment: Clarification:   there should be  zero application tables/partitions in the system tablespace.  And hopefully they didn't create application objects under the SYS or SYSTEM schema . . .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I queried:
SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM dba_extents WHERE tablespace_name='SYSTEM' AND owner <> 'SYS' AND owner <>'SYSTEM'

The results are: OUTLN and DR. As far as I know what os OUTLN user, I am not sure about DR, but - it is like 10 objects smaller then 0,07 MB, so I guess they are not the reason - probably (as you say @ik_zelf) a huge amount of procedures, packages and indexes are. Beside this all users has it's own tablespace default. Do you guys agree with above comment to better increase the next size than the datafile size?

Comment: As long as the tablespace has room to grow it is ok. If filesystem monitoring is not in place, it might be better to pre allocate room for some critical tablespaces. System should be close to static qua size.